# Why do you have to pass this Context as a parameter in Android development?

Tags: android

Its from a lesson on developer.android.com

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

A Context as its first parameter (this is used because the Activity class is a subclass of Context)

=============

Why do you need 'this'?

Comment: It's needed because that constructor requires it so it can create the ComponentName using the package context: [Intent source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/content/Intent.java#Intent.%3Cinit%3E%28android.content.Context%2Cjava.lang.Class%29) Basically to get the package name.

Comment: There are ways of creating an Intent which do not require a Context.  But if you want to target a specific class of a specific package, then providing a context for the *target* package is a ready way to do that.  Note that the above code leverages the fact that the target class is in the same package as the sender, so the sender ("this") when reduced to a package context will also be the proper package context for the target.  That won't always be the case.

Comment: No offence intended but if you're going to get bogged down by wondering *why* a `Context` is needed in so many Android classes and their methods then it will take you a long time to learn Android programming. I'm not saying it's wrong to want to know *why*, just that you will have to do it a lot simply because the `Context` class is very extensive and exposes a lot of methods needed for Android programming.

Comment: I need know do I have to always pass it when calling another activity when I am coding on my own. Thats why. It may take longer to learn this way, but I will have a solid overall understanding of android development.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, that's the best explanation so far, I think I understand now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> public Intent (Context packageContext, Class cls)
>
> Parameters
>
> packageContext    A Context of the application package implementing this
>   class.
>
> cls   The component class that is to be used for the intent.

As you rightly said

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context                 //see this 
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity    // see this
```

Your class extends Activity.

```
public class YouActivity extends Activity // extends Activity
```

Hence `this` refers  to Activity Context and the first param for intent is the same.

Check this link

http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/229-lesson-22-intent-intent-filter-context-theory.html

However i will try to explain better.

Look a the source code

```
3811
3812    public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
3813        mComponent = new ComponentName(packageContext, cls);
3814    }
```

And then

```
61 
62     public ComponentName(Context pkg, String cls) {
63         if (cls == null) throw new NullPointerException("class name is null");
64         mPackage = pkg.getPackageName();  // see this
65         mClass = cls; 
66     }
```

And `getPackageName()` is method of `Context`.

```
public abstract String getPackageName ()

Added in API level 1
Return the name of this application's package.
```

Note

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

This is explicit intent. You'll typically use an explicit intent to start a component in your own app, because you know the class name of the activity or service you want to start.

I am including Chris Stratton's comment as he explains better as to why you need a context as the first param.

> There are ways of creating an Intent which do not require a Context.
>   But if you want to target a specific class of a specific package, then
>   providing a context for the target package is a ready way to do that.
>   Note that the above code leverages the fact that the target class is
>   in the same package as the sender, so the sender ("this") when reduced
>   to a package context will also be the proper package context for the
>   target. That won't always be the case.

Further read Explicit and Implicit Intetns @

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

And also check

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

Comment: This doesn't really explain *why* it is needed however - it just points to the fact that it is.

Comment: @ChrisStratton edited but i am sure it can be better explained.

Comment: @EduardToronto welcome. Do check the edit and the links posted for further understanding

Comment: it's really about the `mPackage = pkg.getPackageName();` part. You could use `setComponent` and create a component out of the class and the package names.