# What is THIS inside a function?

Tags: android, android-intent

Am I right to assume that the value of "this" is the same in the two following propositions ?:

```
public class TheClass extends Activity implements onItemClick {

    public void onItemClick( ... ) {

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, SomeClass.class);          // proposition 1
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(TheClass.this, SomeClass.class); // proposition 2
        ...
    }
}
```

What if TheClass did not implement onItemClick and the intent was created inside an anonymous function ?

edit: TheClass extends Activity

Comment: no in both cases its not a valid context

Comment: this is simply TheClass. onItemClick being an implementation of an abstract method does not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first param for Intent is a valid context. In your case this does not refer to a valid context.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context, java.lang.Class)

Yes `this` and `TheClass.this` refer to `TheClass`. But `TheClass` does not extend `Activity`. This is not what you want. You need a valid context as a first param

```
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(ActivityName.this, SomeClass.class);
```

You may want to check this

[Why do you have to pass this Context as a parameter in Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789793/why-do-you-have-to-pass-this-context-as-a-parameter-in-android-development)

Since your Edit

```
public class TheClass extends Activity implements onItemClick {
```

Both

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, SomeClass.class);          
Intent intent2 = new Intent(TheClass.this, SomeClass.class);
```

refer to `TheClass` which extends Activity

```
java.lang.Object
 ↳    android.content.Context                 //see this 
   ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
       ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
           ↳    android.app.Activity    // see this
```

> What if TheClass did not implement onItemClick and the intent was
>   created inside an anonymous function ?

In case of annonymous inner class use `TheClass.this` as `this` is not a valid context.